# How does DNS work in Brave browser?

Tags: dns, browser

While working from home and connected to my work's VPN, I noticed that DNS queries made by the Edge browser go to my work's DNS server. But DNS queries made by Brave do not. Both browsers have the "use secure dns" setting checked.

Why does this happen/ what is Brave doing differently?

Comment: Which operating system, Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

As doing DNS-queries (secure or no-secure) to a nearest DNS might give away too much of your personal information, many DNS-over-TLS -clients use publicly available resolvers. Obviously, this just shifts the point-of-trust away from your ISP / company, so you need to trust them for not divulging any of your data.

List of such resolvers can be found for example here: https://dnsprivacy.org/wiki/display/DP/DNS+Privacy+Public+Resolvers